# How to remap Caps Lock+HKJL to mouse scroll using Karabiner + Seil?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I've remapped <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>F19</kbd> in Seil.

In Karabiner, I've remapped <kbd>F19</kbd> to <kbd>Hyper</kbd>.

```
<item>
    <name>CAPS to HYPER</name>
    <appendix>Caps to Hyper</appendix>
    <identifier>private.caps_to_hyper</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19,  ModifierFlag::OPTION_R | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19,  ModifierFlag::OPTION_R | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19,  ModifierFlag::OPTION_R | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19,  ModifierFlag::OPTION_R | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R</autogen>
</item>
```

Now, I'm trying to get <kbd>Hyper</kbd> remapped to be mouse scroll when used with <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

```
<item>
    <name>Scroll</name>
    <identifier>private.scroll_keys</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::H,  KeyCode::VK_MOUSEKEY_SCROLL_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::J,  KeyCode::VK_MOUSEKEY_SCROLL_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::K,  KeyCode::VK_MOUSEKEY_SCROLL_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::L,  KeyCode::VK_MOUSEKEY_SCROLL_RIGHT</autogen>
</item>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

(For reference, I also have the following in my `private.xml` file for making <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> arrow keys)

```
<item>
    <name>HJKL Cursors</name>
    <appendix>This uses HJKL to browse System Wide (Left/Down/Up/Right)</appendix>
    <identifier>private.change_browse_to_hjkl</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::H, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::J, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
</item>
```